# Formatting a form using rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i format a form on a rails app?
I have my application.css file, no classes where gives or ids to the form tags inside of the form action page. but the form inherited the formatting in somehow but it is not what i wanted.

Also, how can i make every single page in my rails app have its own page and css file?
i don't want to make one master page and imbed the pages codes inside the body tag

like i want to have every single page its own application.html.erb and how to let rails know about this and not to load the default one?

I'm a php guy, so working with styling and templates very confusing to me.
when i want to format a form using css. i know how to do it, also i write the code like below:

```
<form id="FirstForm">
```

in my rails app tutorial i followed, there is no id tages or formatting inside the form tags and fields at all. don't know how this got formatted? is it allowed to write ids and classes inside of the rails form tag?

Comment: Why don't you check the resulting html?

Comment: i know how to do this with html and css only, but the tutorials breaks down the codes to several pages. i want to have every single page its own template full template head and body and footer tag, and inside the ruby code i want to insert the css ids and classes to make it easy for me to edit my styling needs in the future.

Comment: Understood, I gave more details in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `id` and `class` as you desire.

Example:

```
<%= form_for @article, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => {:id => "FirstForm", :class => "your_class"} do |f| %>
```

Check [full doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear answer. now how can i use the <%= form-for> and fields tags in my create action page along with full html code for this action page only? i don't want to use the other templates html tags and body and footer to be used with my create action page, create action page now only contains the form code and new styles i added to it. how about the full html page by creating application.html.erb for it?